# "The constructor should be payable if you send value" but constructor is NOT payable and didn't send any value

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, ico, constructor

When copiling an ICO contract using http://remix.ethereum.org/ and JS VM environment the following error is thrown:

```
"VM error: invalid opcode. The constructor should be payable if you send value. The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information."
```

Didn't send any value and the constructor is not a payable function. So why the error?

The contract source code is at: https://gist.github.com/computerphysicslab/3990c706a2f36fed56e31e72f59b61fb

Any hint? Thx!

Refs.:

- [Solidity/Remix Error : The constructor should be payable if you send value. How to solve this?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27001/solidity-remix-error-the-constructor-should-be-payable-if-you-send-value-how)
- [Solidity/Web3.js Cannot send value to non-payable constructor](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/solidity-web3-js-cannot-send-value-to-non-payable-constructor)

Comment: I have found out one of the require() assertions fails. That's probably the cause of the error. So the error description is quite misleading to me...

Answer (score 1):

This error jumps out for some (unpredictable) reasons when, may be, the internal remix ide stack is corrupted and/or your deployment silently fails.

Very often if you save, exit and reload it does not appear anymore.

If it appears again and again with your code, try to save/exit/reload and then deploy it again using a 10x gas limit.

I encountered this problem in 0.6.3 and 0.6.4 (currently online) version of remix ide. I hope it will be fixed for the next 0.7.0 (that is the alpha version today).

In these cases it is a system error, anyway. Your code is not affected if not for the amount of gas required in order to deploy it.